# Using Edge or Chrome to debug Flutter Applications

Tags: flutter, google-chrome, debugging, google-cloud-firestore, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to debug my app using edge.

And the first time it run...

[image]

It throws me exception saying...

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following ImageCodecException was thrown resolving an image codec:
Failed to load network image.
Image URL: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/eCx7dzYqb98/maxresdefault.jpg
Trying to load an image from another domain? Find answers at:
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/web-images
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
Image provider: CachedNetworkImageProvider("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/eCx7dzYqb98/maxresdefault.jpg",
scale: 1)
 Image key: CachedNetworkImageProvider("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/eCx7dzYqb98/maxresdefault.jpg",
scale: 1):
  CachedNetworkImageProvider("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/eCx7dzYqb98/maxresdefault.jpg", scale: 1)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Another exception was thrown: ImageCodecException: Failed to load network image.
Another exception was thrown: ImageCodecException: Failed to load network image.
```

But after I reloaded / restarted app...

Everything is working fine...

[image]

**What is the reason for this?**

When I debug on my mobile phone (I'm using it as emulator) everything is working fine...

Comment: please check the suggestions in this stackoverflow [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66644024/18265638) & [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68802349/18265638)

Comment: Please provide code for the widgets in question (Network Images). We can't help with resolving this issue if we can't even see what's wrong in the first place.